# Cell array to Numpy array in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a cell object array. It is a .mat file. After I read that file it is a dictionary. Then when I upload that dictionary, I got an object array of dimension (1,260). Actually, each array has values with a dimension of (128,128). I want to extract each array from that cell array. I need help.

```
from scipy.io import loadmat 
data = loadmat('bispec.mat')
locals().update(data)



result
------------
data (type dictionary & size 4)
then, bspec (type object, size = (1,260))
```

Comment: what is a "cell array"?

Comment: cell array is a data type that uses an indexed data container called a cell. Each cell can contain any data type. For example a cella array contains 260 object arrays where each object array has values (128,128)

Comment: you have a lot to clarify here; starting with how a cell array is a matlab term, not a python term, then how did you read that file, how it ended in a dictionary, etc. Post the code.

Comment: done. I have clarified

Answer (score 0):

If your array is saved in a .mat file, it is stored (usually) as a dictionnary, so to access your data, you'd need to know the name of the entry that, apparently, contains 260 objects, with each of these objects being a 128x128 array.
You could access them with

```
data = loadmat('bispec.mat')
data = data["the name you should know"]
data = np.array(data)
```

And you'd now have a 260x128x128 numpy array.

Comment: after loading data, I am getting one dictionary named data (which type is  dictionary & size is 4). After that if I locals().update(data) then it returns a variable called bspec which has  (type object, size = (1,260)). So please be clear on your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

In Octave

```
>> x = {zeros(2,3),ones(2,3)}
x =
{
  [1,1] =

     0   0   0
     0   0   0

  [1,2] =

     1   1   1
     1   1   1

}
>> save -7 bispec.mat x
```

In Ipython

```
In [71]: from scipy import io
In [72]: data = io.loadmat('bispec.mat')
In [73]: data
Out[73]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.0.0, 2018-04-12 06:40:36 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([[array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
         array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])]], dtype=object)}
In [74]: data['x']
Out[74]: 
array([[array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
        array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])]], dtype=object)
In [75]: _.shape
Out[75]: (1, 2)
In [76]: data['x'][0,0]
Out[76]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [77]: data['x'][0,1]
Out[77]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

The `cell` was loaded as a 2d array of dtype object.  The simplest way to access the component arrays is to index them.

If we squeeze `x` to 1d, we can use some version of `concatenate` to join the elements into one array (assuming compatible shapes).

```
In [78]: data['x'].squeeze()
Out[78]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]]),
       array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])], dtype=object)
In [79]: np.stack(data['x'].squeeze())
Out[79]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
In [80]: _.shape
Out[80]: (2, 2, 3)
```

In the most general case, `cell` can have matrices with differing sizes.  It can also be 2d, not just a column or row cell.  Then this 'stacking' doesn't work.